# Native x64 dll does not work

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I have an application that I compile as x86 code but as a separate version, as x64 code as well. The application basically has two parts, a c# managed exe and a c++ unmanaged dll. I have problems with the latter. On my development PC (Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2008) I create a setup with a deployment project and this setup installs the application in Program Files... as it should and the application runs. I also have a test PC (Windows 7 64-bit with practically nothing else). There the application still installs into Program Files... but it does not run, I get the BadImageFormatException when a function (any function) of the unmanaged dll is called. The problem is that my own project that produces the dll also makes use of quite a few freely available libraries (e.g. glew32, openal, freeimage, etc.) I took as much care is possible to make sure that I use the x64 versions of these libraries, but something still must be wrong. For some reason one of the libraries used by my dll is not available as x64 code on the test PC but it is on the development PC. At least that is the only explanation I have at the moment why my setup works on the development PC but not on the test PC.
My question is: how can I find out where the problem is. The error message I receive does not tell any helpful detail. I tried to analyze my dll with depends but it looks OK. It lists a lot of dependent libraries as X86 (these are probably system files) but all those that I use on purpose are listed as x64.
Is there any way to test why the Windows on my test PC tries to run the DLL as x86 code even though it should be x64?
Thanks.

I noticed something very strange: My application is being deployed in the Program Files folder as it should be for a x64 application but it fails to run. However if I copy all the files in the folder it is installed to to another folder (inside the Documents folder) the application runs perfectly.

Comment: Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to see exactly what DLL is being found.

Answer (score 0):

Run [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the machine where you want to diagnose the issue. Look carefully at the logs and you'll see exactly which dlls are being loaded, and where from.

Comment: I guess this is for .net assemblies and the problem is with an unmanaged dll. Nevertheless I tried the fusion log viewer and there is no entry in the list.

Comment: It covers native dlls as well, you have to tweak the settings. I also have a mixed solution and I used this successfully in the past. You also need to tell it to log bind failures. I might make a blog post about it soon.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to tweak the settings? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have build your .NET executable (or DLL) with `Any CPU` configuration, and you have given x64/Win32 native DLL for Win32/x64 (i.e. wrong config).

- On x64 systems, your .NET binary will try to load the native DLL as if native DLL is x64.
- And on 32-bit systems, it will try to load 32-bit native DLL.

Comment: No, I have built both the c# exe and the unmanaged c++ dll specifically as x64.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was not the 64-bit dll at all. One of the libraries I did not make but I link to (I do not know which yet, there) seems to try to write a file to the application folder. Of course, this is not allowed inside the Program Files folder unless you run the application as an administrator. Sorry for asking help for the wrong question.